# Android App screen differs from Designer View in Visual Studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have read quite a lot information about this, but can't seem to get in right. For seem reason I can't get the application screen simular as what I designed in Visual Studio.

I have updated my AndroidManifext.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Doorgang_Lite.Doorgang_Lite" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
  <application 
   android:label="Doorgang_Lite"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>    
</manifest>
```

But no lick so far.

Below Layout was created in Visual Studio 2015 (Xamarin Android Form).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Please enter your pincode" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NmbOne"
        android:src="@drawable/oc"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NmbTwo"
        android:src="@drawable/oc"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/NmbOne" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NmbThree"
        android:src="@drawable/oc"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/NmbTwo" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NmbFour"
        android:src="@drawable/oc"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/NmbThree" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/TWEE"
        android:src="@drawable/twee"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/EEN"
        android:src="@drawable/een"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TWEE" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DRIE"
        android:src="@drawable/drie"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TWEE" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/VIJF"
        android:src="@drawable/vijf"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Twee"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/VIER"
        android:src="@drawable/vier"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Een"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/VIJF" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ZES"
        android:src="@drawable/zes"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Drie"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Vijf" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ACHT"
        android:src="@drawable/acht"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Vijf"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ZEVEN"
        android:src="@drawable/zeven"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Vier"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ACHT" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NEGEN"
        android:src="@drawable/negen"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Zes"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Acht" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NL"
        android:src="@drawable/nl"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Acht"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/BLANCO"
        android:src="@drawable/blanco"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Zeven"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/NL" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/BACK"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Negen"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/NL" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how the two screens look like

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0):

Found it...you need to be very carefully with caps and small caps in your XML files.
In my case for example I referred one time to ID ""@+id/ACHT" and in a next case to "@+id/Acht".

Building this didn't cause issues, but the result in your app is what has been described above.